# How to print hexdump with indent

Tags: string, go, hexdump

`fmt.Println(hex.Dump([]byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}))`

It shows:

```
00000000  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  09 00 01 02 03 04 05 06  |................|
00000010  07 08 09 00                                       |....|
```

How to add an indent before the hex addresses to **all** lines? like

```
    00000000  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  09 00 01 02 03 04 05 06  |................|
    00000010  07 08 09 00                                       |....|
```

Split the lines by *\n* then put an indent before each line will do, but is there any built-in tool does this? I tried `hex.Dumper` and `tabwriter.NewWriter`, but they just treat the indent as normal data and printed along with the hex dump.

Comment: You probably need to add a tab, or other indentation character(s) before each line. What have you tried?

Comment: "but is there any built-in tool does this?" -- Not exactly this. But you can use a combination of `bytes.Split` and `bytes.Join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hex.Dump()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#Dump) returns a formatted string. If you want it to be formatted like indenting every line, replace all newline characters with a newline + indentation (e.g. tab). Plus prepend the indentation to the start of it so the first line will also be indented (which is not preceeded by a newline char).

For replacing, use [`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll).

See this example:

```
s := hex.Dump([]byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0})
fmt.Println(s)

s = "\t" + strings.ReplaceAll(s, "\n", "\n\t")
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0-V7GH8ej8G)):

```
00000000  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  09 00 01 02 03 04 05 06  |................|
00000010  07 08 09 00 01 02 03 04  05 06 07 08 09 00 01 02  |................|
00000020  03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00                           |........|

    00000000  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08  09 00 01 02 03 04 05 06  |................|
    00000010  07 08 09 00 01 02 03 04  05 06 07 08 09 00 01 02  |................|
    00000020  03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00                           |........|
```